# Changing class variables inside of __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to update the number of people in the code below by adding one every time an instance of the class is performed, it used to work for me but I tried the code today and it isn't working. Also when i try and print the "User.people" variable it returns what I assume is its address in the memory. Please help me.

```
class User:

    people = int(0)

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, age):
        self.name = first_name + " " + last_name
        self.age = age
        User.people += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} is {self.age} years old"

    def __del__(self):
        User.people -= 1

    def people(self):
        print(f"There are now {self.people} in the class and his name is {self.name}")
        return self.people

person1 = User("Greg", "Mitchel", 76)
person2 = User("Michael", "Hutton", 16)
print(User.people)
print(person1)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Downloads/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    person1 = User("Greg", "Mitchel", 76)
  File "C:/Users/User/Downloads/test.py", line 8, in __init__
    User.people += 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'function' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that you gave the same name to two different class attributes: first, the simple variable; later you redefined `people` as an instance method.  By the time you try to alter the population count, `people` is redefined as a method, so the increment is illegal.  Simply change one name:

```
def report_pop(self):
    print(f"There are now {self.people} in the class and his name is {self.name}")
    return self.people
```

Comment: OMG thank you, i feel really dumb now that i know why it wasn't working. You are a life saver!

Comment: No, I just saved you some sleep.  You already have an error message that tells you `people` is a function.

Comment: Yeah i saw that and i was thinking that isn't a function, I guess i was too focused on trying to find where i went wrong that i totally missed the fact that it was a function name.